# Magento2 Update product description page on extension/plugin/module installation

Tags: magento2

How can I update the product description page `catalog_product_view.xml` on a plugin installation.

I've to develop a plugin which should add an additional button on the product description page.

Is there any hooks or do I have to use interceptors? I haven't tried any code so I can't share it here as I can't figure out how to update the product description page.

Please share necessary information and if possible a sample code to do the same.